# Power series uniform convergence: equivalent statements or not?

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently studying power series and I just went through the proof of the following theorem:

> If the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ converges at some point $x_0
>  \in \mathbf{R}$, then it converges uniformly on $[-r, r]$ where $0 \le
>  r < |x_0|$.

My question is: Can I rewrite the theorem equivalently as,

> If the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ converges at some point $x_0
>  \in \mathbf{R}$, then it converges uniformly on $(-|x_0|, |x_0|)$?

To me, it appears that both statements are the same, am I right in thinking this? If I am wrong, can someone point out the (subtle) differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the claimed domain where your power series converges uniformly.

5xum gave a nice example where the power series converges in $x_0=-1$ and uniformly on $[-r,r]$ where $0<r<1$ but not on $(-|x_0|,|x_0|)=(-1,1)$.

The difference appears if $x_0$ is a boundary point of the domain of your power series. For a power series $S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ you can compute
$$
R=\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\right)^{-1}.
$$
If $|x_0|<R$ then your power series converges. Moreover you can choose $x_1\in(-R,R)$ such that $|x_0|<|x_1|<R$. Therefore $S(x)$ converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$ for $0<r<|x_1|$ especially on $[-|x_0|,|x_0|]$ or $(-|x_0|,|x_0|)$.

If $|x_0|>R$ then $S(x_0)$ is divergent and we are done.

But the case $|x_0|=R$ is special. In general we need a smaller domain to get the uniformly convergence of $S(x)$.

This is not just restricted on power series. You can also consider 
$$
f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},~f_n(x):=x^n.
$$
Then $(f_n)_n$ converges not uniformly while $(f_n\mid_{[0,r]})_n$ does for all $0<r<1$. Therefore you can't go to the limit while keeping all properties.

**Edit:**

Question: Why is $S(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1nx^n$ not uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$?

Answer: Define $S_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1nx^n$. $S$ is uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$ if
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{x\in(-1,1)}|S(x)-S_k(x)|=0.
$$
Now consider that $S(x)=-\ln(1-x)$ and we get
$$
\sup_{x\in(-1,1)}|S(x)-S_k(x)|\geq\lim_{x\to 1}|S(x)-S_k(x)|=\lim_{x\to 1}\left|-\ln(1-x)-\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1nx^n\right|=\infty.
$$
Therefore $S$ can't be uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$.

As described above the boundary of the domain yields the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is such an indepth and excellent answer. Before I accept your answer, I have one last query, could you please show me the reasoning/proof as to why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$ does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, the two statements are certainly not identical. In fact, the second statement is wrong, because

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

converges, but not uniformly, on $(-1,1)$.